# Why std::compare_three_way is not a template struct/functor

Tags: c++, c++20

For example, the compare of `std::less` is defined as a template struct

```
template< class T = void >
struct less;
```

While `std::compare_three_way` is defined just as a normal struct, and its `operator()` is a template function. (code from MSVC)

```
struct compare_three_way {
    template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
        requires three_way_comparable_with<_Ty1, _Ty2> // TRANSITION, GH-489
    constexpr auto operator()(_Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) const
        noexcept(noexcept(_STD forward<_Ty1>(_Left) <=> _STD forward<_Ty2>(_Right))) /* strengthened */ {
        return _STD forward<_Ty1>(_Left) <=> _STD forward<_Ty2>(_Right);
    }

    using is_transparent = int;
};
```

So why isn't `std::compare_three_way` a template struct?

```
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
    requires three_way_comparable_with<_Ty1, _Ty2>
struct compare_three_way {
    constexpr auto operator()(_Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) const; 
};
```

---

By the way, could I replace `std::less<T>` by `std::three_way_compare` in my own implementation of containers, like `Comparer<T>` in C#.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want it to be a class template instead of having the operator templated? Or are you asking why it's inconsistent?

Comment: @chris To use it in template, like `std::less<T>` in `std::set<T>`

Comment: I think std::less<T> is something historical, that's why since c++14, there is a <T=void> specialization, meaning that you don't really need to provide T, T can be deduced from argument deduction.

Comment: `std::less<T>` gives you a type capable of comparing `T`s. `std::compare_three_way` gives you a type capable of comparing `T`s. (`std::less<>` also gives you a type capable of comparing `T`s.) The containers require something that is capable of comparing `T`s. There's a faulty assumption here somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

The comparison of original `std::less` (and its friends) are defined as such:

```
bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

As this function call operator is not a template, it can only compare objects of the type that is used to instantiate the `std::less` template.

In a later language revision, these comparators were extended with specialisation `std::less<>` to support comparing objects of different types by templating the the function call operator itself:

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs));
```

This largely obsoletes the homogeneous versions (`std::less<T>`) in most use cases because it is either equivalent, or more efficient due to not forcing a conversion to a common type. The old homogeneous comparators are retained for backward compatibility.

Heterogeneous lookup was an existing thing when `std::compare_three_way` was proposed, so the homogeneous version was never introduced.

> To use it in template, like `std::less<T>` in `std::set<T>`

You can use `std::compare_three_way` in  `std::set<T>` and `std::set<U>` etc. (figuratively) just like you can use `std::less<>`. You (probably) don't need `std::less<T>` nor  `std::less<U>` - nor `std::compare_three_way<T>` which doesn't exist.

Comment: `std::ranges::less` isn't a class template either, though it was originally: [P1291R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1291r0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like the `std::compare_three_way` performs forwarding, it could not work when the template parameters are for a `struct`. [C++ Standard section 13.10.3.2 §3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3):

> A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter **that does not represent a template parameter of a class template** (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).

Thus, here `_Ty1&&` and `_Ty2&&` are just rvalue references, and there is no way to forward them correctly:

```
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
    requires three_way_comparable_with<_Ty1, _Ty2>
struct compare_three_way {
    constexpr auto operator()(_Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) const; 
};
```

The template struct declared above only accepts rvalue expressions as its operands, which would not be too useful. The only way to have this `struct` be usable is to make the arguments `const` references. The MSVC implementers have opted for the forwarding way instead.